Problem 1.49 (b): Algebraic Curves - Fulton
I'm trying to solve this exercise for quite some time, but I need help.

Let $L$ be a field, $k$ an algebraic closed subfield of $L$.
(a) Show that any element of $L$ that is algebraic over $k$ is already in $k$.
(b) An algebraic closed field has no module-finite field extensions except itself.

I've been successful proving (a), but not so much with (b).
I saw the proof below on some website:

Suppose $L$ is a module-finite field extension of an algebraically closed field $k$. That is, $L$ is a finitely generated $k$-module. Let $a_1, \cdots, a_n$ be a finite generating set for $L$ as a $k$=module. Sinte $k$ is algebraically closed, each $a_i$ is algebraic over $k$ by part (a). Thus, there existis a non-zero polynomial $F_i(a_i)=0$ for each $i=1, \cdots, n$. Let $F(x)=f_1(x)f_2(x)\cdots f_n(x) \in k[x]$. Then, $F(x)$ is a non-zero polynomial, and for each $i$ we have $F(x)=0$. Now, consider the element $b \in L$. Since $a_1, \cdots, a_n$ generate $L$ as a $k$-module, we can write $b=c_1a_1+\cdots+c_na_n$, for some $c_1, \cdots, c_n \in k$. Then:
$$F(b)=F(c_1a_1+c_2a_2+\cdots+c_na_n)=c_1F(a_1)+c_2F(a_2)+\cdots+c_nF(a_n)=0.$$
Thus, $F(x)$ is a non-zero polynomial in $k[x]$ that has every elemente of $L$ as a root. However, this contractis the fact that $k$ is algebraically closed, since a non-zero polynomial in $k[x]$ can have at most $deg(F)$ roots in $k$.

What I do not understand is this last equality: $F(c_1a_1+c_2a_2+\cdots+c_na_n)=c_1F(a_1)+c_2F(a_2)+\cdots+c_nF(a_n)$.
If someone can help me, I'd be grateful.
(P.S.: English is not my first language, so I'm sorry for any mistakes made.)

The solution you have cited doesn't make any sense to me since $F$ may not be linear. You can conclude (b) directly from (a) by noting that if $L/k$ is an extension of fields where $L$ is finite (as a module) over $k$, then $L/k$ is automatically algebraic, and hence, the trivial extension.
